# Replace individual character element of a string C

Tags: c, string, replace, character

I am trying to do something really basic on C but I keep getting a segmentation fault. All I want to do is replace a letter of a word with a different letter- in this example replace the l with a L. Can anyone help explain where I have gone wrong? It should be a really basic problem I think, I just have no idea why its not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *string1;

    string1 = "hello";
    printf("string1 %s\n", string1);    

    printf("string1[2] %c\n", string1[2]);
    string1[2] = 'L';
    printf("string1 %s\n", string1);

    return 0;
}
```

For my output I get

> string1 hello
>   string1[2] l
>   Segmentation fault

Thanks!

Comment: String1 is a pointer to read-only memory (in most systems) as it is a constant initializer.   You can't write to that string without copying it first.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> ```
> string1 = "hello";
> string1[2] = 'L';
> ```

You [can't change string literals](http://c-faq.com/strangeprob/strlitnomod.html), it's undefined behavior. Try this:

```
char string1[] = "hello";
```

Or maybe:

```
char *string1;
string1 = malloc(6); /* hello + 0-terminator */
strcpy(string1, "hello");

/* Stuff. */

free(string1);
```

Comment: Nothing big but you can use strdup("hello") instead of a call to malloc and strcpy. strdup do this for you, it's more convenient to use

Comment: @Zoneur Yup, I often recommend `strdup` but it's sometimes problematic because it's not standard.

Comment: If I want change this value ? "hello"  to "helxo" you code not work.... to change specific value ( in a pointer ) ...Replace individual character element of a string C

Answer (score 4):

```
char *string1;
string1 = "hello";
```

`string1` points to a string literal and string literals are non-modifiable.

What you can do is initialize an array with the elements of a string literal.

```
char string1[] =  "hello";
```

the elements of `string1` array are modifiable.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *string1 = "hello";
```

When running the code, the string literal will be in a section that is read-only. OS does not allow the code to change that block of memory, so you get a seg-fault.

```
char string1[] = "hello";
```

The string literal will be pushed onto the stack when you run the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string1[2] = 'L';
```

you are trying to change a string literal which is undefined behavior in C.
Instead use `string1[]="hello";` 
Segmentation fault you get is because the literal is probably stored in the the read only section of the memory and trying to write to it produces undefined behavior.