# Change value in pointer string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

Is it possible to change a value in a character array initialized by a string pointer this way:

```
char *word;
word = (char*) malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
word = "Test";
word[2] = 'w';

return 0;
```

I get a segmentation fault while executing the above code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Warning: You [should not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the return of malloc. Second warning: when calling `sizeof` in `malloc` (and the like) [you should always write it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17258659/1151654) as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr) * ...);` instead of `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptrtype*) * ...);`.

Comment: `word = "Test";` assigns the address of the string litteral `"Test"` to `word`, overwriting what you got in there with `malloc` in the first place. You don't seem to know what you are doing at all there and maybe should get a good tutorial or good book on C programming

Comment: You might have to, or you might [search how to do it](https://www.google.fr/search?q=C+change+char+in+string) and then try [what you found is supposed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149327/replace-individual-character-element-of-a-string-c).

Answer (score 7):

You get a crash because you do this:

```
word = "Test";
word[2] = 'w';
```

The first assignment *changes* the pointer, so it no longer points to the memory you have allocated but to a string literal. And string literals are actually read-only character arrays. And as they are read-only, your attempt of modifying the array in the second assignment will lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The correct way is to *copy* the string to the memory you have allocated, which you do with the [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function:

```
strcpy(word, "test");
```

---

Another thing with the reassigning of the pointer is that you then loose the pointer to the allocated memory, and have a memory leak. You can not call `free` on the pointer either, since the memory pointed to by `word` (after your original reassignment) is no longer allocated by you, which would have caused another case of undefined behavior.

Comment: Just a last question. If "Test" is a string literal, why can I alter it if the array is declared by the standard array declaration word[]? I want to catch the internal representation of both declarations.

Comment: @morophla Because then you create a local array that you can modify like any other local variable.

Comment: So the declaration "char word[] = "Test" acts like a strcpy? The string literal is copied at the adress of the first element of the array this way?

Answer (score 1):

**Point 1**

You don't assign *strings* after `malloc()`. Otherwise, you'll be leaking memory. Use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) instead.

Also, please [do not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family.

**Point 2**

[Without `malloc()`] *string literals* (here, `"Test"`) are usually stored in read only memory. Trying to alter them will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Ref: As per `C11` standard, chapter §6.4.5, string literals, (emphasis mine)

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

in your code,

```
word[2] = 'w';
```

is trying to alter the *string literal*. And segmentation fault is one of the side effects of UB.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous problems in your code.

- You should [never cast the result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) because doing so is pointless and potentially dangerous.
- In C you copy strings with strcpy(), not with the assignment operator =.
- Since you never copied the string but just told the pointer to point some place else, you created a memory leak.
- And since you never copied the string, but are rather just pointing at a string literal, you invoke undefined behavior because you attempt to modify the contents of a string literal. (Remove the malloc line and you'll still have this bug.)
- You don't seem to free() the memory nor check the return value of malloc.

Correct code:

```
char* word;
word = malloc(10);
if(word == NULL)
{
  // out of memory, error handling here
}

strcpy(word, "Test");
word[2] = 'w'; // should give "Tewt"
...
free(word);
```

Comment: So you say we should never cast a malloc in C. But in C++ the casting is obligatory right?

Comment: @morophla Yes. One of many cases where the languages aren't compatible. It doesn't really matter because you shouldn't be using malloc in C++ anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the pointer pointing to a string literal the you can't. If it is an array of character then it is possible.

In the snippet given, you allocated memory for `word` using `malloc` and then you are assigning a string literal to `word` which let the `word` point to first character of `Test` and the previous allocated memory is not pointed by it anymore and it will cause a memory leak. In this case you can't modify `Test` by `word[2] = 'w';`. It will invoke undefined behavior.

Instead of `word = "Test";`, use `strcpy` to copy string

```
strcpy(word, "Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet should probably look more like this:

```
int maxlen = 10;
char *word;
word = malloc(maxlen * sizeof(char));
strncpy(word, "Test", maxlen);
word[2] = 'w';

return 0;
```

Comment: So while initializing an array like word[] = "Test", does it means the content of the string literal is copied in the array, more or less like strcpy?

Comment: @morophia You can do `char word[] = "Test";` which will allocate memory on stack (not on heap) and initializes the char array with the given string. But the string must be known at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

1) the pointer is 'word' is being replaced. 
 That results in a memory leak

2) a literal is in readonly memory, 
so trying to change anything in that memory results in a seg fault event

Comment: So while initializing an array like word[] = "Test", does it means the content of the string literal is copied in the array, more or less like strcpy?