# Convert forward slashes to backlashes

Tags: c, string, loops

Here is my attempted code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *convertDirec(char direc[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(direc); i++){
        if(direc[i]=='/'){
            direc[i]=='\\';
        }
    }
    return direc;
}

int main(){
    printf("%s", convertDirec("C:/Users/user/Documents/data.csv"));
}
```

However, the `printf` statement in `main` simply prints the same path. I found another resource online about this, and the logic seemed identical to mine, so I am not sure where my error is. I attempted doing `direc[i] == "/"`, but this gave the same results. I also attempted to replace random letters, but this also failed.

I also attempted to do this using a pointer, but that didn't work either.

```
char *convertDirec(char direc[]){
    for(char *p = direc; *p != '\0'; ++p){
        if(*p == '/')
            *p='\\';
    }
    return direc;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `"C:/Users/user/Documents/data.csv"` this is a char literal and read only...

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings: it should alert you to the problem of passing a const array to your function.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I may be misunderstanding, but doesn't the function assign it as such `char direc[] = "C:/Users/user/Documents/data.csv"`, which is not a literal no?

Comment: even if it did, where would the buffer be allocated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149327/replace-individual-character-element-of-a-string-c <-I tried following this

Comment: @hkj447 : no. It passes the array (of const chars) to the function, which then points direc to that memory space.

Comment: argh it's a typo question... `==` instead of `=`

Comment: I'm afraid I have to close this. I'm sure this typo happened a lot of times, plus the literal modification error, ... enabling the warnings should be enough.

Comment: BTW you don't generally have to do that, since Windows recognizes paths with slashes.

Answer (score 8):

Let the compiler help you:

```
test.c: In function ‘convertDirec’:
test.c:8:21: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
             direc[i]=='\\';
             ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

This compares the current char to `'\\'` and throws the result away (hence, the warning).

The second version fails, because the char literal isn't writable and writing to it is undefined behavior, so you need to either copy it to a memory location you may write to or get a non-const `char*` from somewhere else:

```
//Same as above

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    printf("%s", convertDirec(argv[1]));
}
```

```
$ ./test c:/Users/
c:\Users\
```

Comment: Ideally, you should check that `argv[1]` is not the null pointer (`argc > 1`) before using it.

Answer (score 6):

`direc[i] == '\\';` should be `direc[i] = '\\';`, that's why nothing happens.

Of course, if you fix it, you most likely get a crash because you shouldn't write to a string literal. You can do this instead:

```
int main() {
    char string[] = "C:/Users/user/Documents/data.csv"; // you can modify this copy
    printf("%s", convertDirec(string));
}
```